# change the children index of stackpanel in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, stackpanel

I want to know how I can change the **children index** of a StackPanel in **c# code**.

For example, I want to make the child that is currently second to be displayed first. I need animation when changing the index.

I am using a StackPanel because I need the Orientation property to stack all elements and keep them grouped together. If you have better idea to use another control, I am open to that.

Answer (score 6):

[StackPanel.Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) is a [UIElementCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.aspx) that easily allows to reorder elements by e.g. its [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.insert.aspx) and [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.removeat.aspx) methods.

Comment: you mean remove all and reInsert them ?

Comment: Or just remove one at position i and insert it at position j.

Comment: read my last edit please

Comment: Well, then why not write some code that reorders the children and run it by a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) or so?