# WPF ordering XAML elements in StackPanel at runtime based on a config file

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm developing a WPF app using MVVM pattern with Caliburn.Micro
I have a config file that contains positions of where XAML elements should be inside of a StackPanel

```py
# in this case RU_ELEMENT should be at the top, EN_ELEMENT second and DE_ELEMENT last
EN_ELEMENT = 1
DE_ELEMENT = 2
RU_ELEMENT = 0
```

This seems to be pretty basic yet I'm unable to find a way to do this. I found this thread: [change the children index of stackpanel in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488738/change-the-children-index-of-stackpanel-in-wpf) but changing it this way seems to be too complicated for what I am after. I just need to set an index of an element from a variable. I feel like there should be a much simpler way. I'm also ok with using some other, perhaps more appropriate layout panel than StackPanel.

XAML:

```xml
<!--     Language1 -->
<TextBlock Text="English" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="16"/>
<TextBox
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Height="150"
    Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ValueEN, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    cm:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action FocusedTextBox('english')]" />

<!--     Language2 -->
<TextBlock Text="German" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="16"/>
<TextBox
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Height="150"
    Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ValueDE, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    cm:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action FocusedTextBox('german')]" />
```

*On a side note: I find WPF and C# in general to have much less discussions and "how to" guides than all of my previous languages (Java, Python, JS) so researching things online is usually a dead end for me. I'm not sure to why that is since C# is a very popular language but I'm really struggling with finding help online.*

Comment: So you're creating the view first, then trying to reshuffle things? Why don't you just parse and sort your file first then add the elements in the correct order in the first place? You can still define your chunks of xaml as resources or DataTemplates.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I'm completely fine with doing it this way (it would be the preferable way actually). The problem is I'm unable to find information on how to do it this way. My guess is I would have as many different xaml files as I have things to order and then parse them inside of main XAML depending on name of the files?

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to use an `ItemsControl` that would host the xaml elements. You can bind the items like `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems} ...`
Then you could easily sort the items in the corresponding ViewModel. Like so:

```
public BindableCollection<YourElement> ListOfItems {get;set;}
...
ListOfItems.Sort()
```

Note that `YourElement` class should have a comparator.

EDIT: As per request I'll explain it more detailed:

In your Xaml you have to declare a ItemsControl like so:

```xml
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Language}" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="16"/>
                    <TextBox
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Height="150"
                        Text="{Binding TextValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        cm:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action FocusedTextBox($this)]" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And in your backend you should first create a class that's going to represent your item in the ItemsControl. For example:

```
public Class MyItem{
    public string Language {get;set;}
    public string TextValue {get;set;}
}
```

Finally in your ViewModel you'll need to create the list of items that you bind with the ItemsControl like so:

```
public BindableCollection<MyItem> ListOfItems {get;set;}= new BindableCollection<MyItem>();

//here you can add them in the order that is specified by the config file
public void LoadItems(){
    ListOfItems.Add(new MyItem{Language="English"});
    ListOfItems.Add(new MyItem{Language="Russian"});
    ListOfItems.Add(new MyItem{Language="German"});
}

public void FocusedTextBox(MyItem item){
    //do here whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it with binding alone but the whole thing was getting out of hand and I deleted everything as it wasn't pretty at all. I like your solution but frankly I don't really know how to implement it. I updated my post with example of my XAML. With your way I should be somehow writing the XAML that I want to change order of in C# and not in the XAML view?

A comparator could be a simple constant integer that every `YourElement` would have but How can I display XAML using a Collection of objects?